# Applying weights to KNN dimensions

Tags: elasticsearch, knn, euclidean-distance, opensearch

When doing a KNN searches in ES/OS it seems to be recommended to normalize the data in the knn vectors to prevent single dimensions from over powering the the final scoring.

In my current example I have a 3 dimensional vector where all values are normalized to values between 0 and 1

```
[0.2, 0.3, 0.2]
```

From the perspective of Euclidian distance based scoring this seems to give equal weight to all dimensions.

In my particular example I am using an l2 vector:

```
"method": {
            "name": "hnsw",
            "space_type": "l2",
            "engine": "nmslib",
          }
```

However, if I want to give more weight to one of my dimensions (say by a factor of 2), would it be acceptable to single out that dimension and normalize between 0-2 instead of the base range of 0-1?

Example:

```
[0.2, 0.3, 1.2] // Third vector is now between 0-2
```

The distance computation for this term would now be `(2 * (xi - yi))^2` and lead to bigger diffs compared to the rest. As a result the overall score would be more sensitive to differences in this particular term.

In OS the score is calculated as `1 / (1 + Distance Function)` so the higher the value returned from the distance function, the lower the score will be.

Is there a method to deciding what the weighting range should be? Setting the range too high would likely make the dimension too dominant?

Comment: are you doing this in OpenSearch or Elasticsearch?

Comment: Technically OpenSearch, but I think the two rely on the same approach wrt distance

Comment: There is one more reason for normalising the data: to avoid big values for the distance. Since we divide by (1+ distance) to compute the score, when the order of magnitude of the distance is big, the score becomes a very small positive number and it more sensitive to round off errors.  
You can add weights as you see fit (trial and error is probably the easiest way to find suitable weights), but be mindful of the order of magnitude of the distance.